# tags uint32 and uint32-t are synonymous

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

While editing the tag wiki, I noticed that there is a tag [uint32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uint32) and a [uint32-t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uint32-t), and there is even [a question that asks about the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362084/difference-between-uint32-and-uint32-t) in C++ between the two types. Is the difference (one being standard, the other not) significant enough to justify two tags?

There is also a [uint8t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uint8t) that does not have a counterpart without t, but nothing for the 16bits,64bits and 128bits versions.

Actually I came to wonder if we need all those int variations at all. An expert in [int32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int32) is likely to also be expert in [uint32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uint32) and [int64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int64) since to my knowledge the memory representation of integers does not vary much across compilers and languages (only sign bit versus 2's complement).

Should something be done about this list of tags?

Here is the complete list that I found: 
[int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int),
[uint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uint),
[uint8t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uint8t),
[uint16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uint16),
[int32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int32),
[uint32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uint32),
[uint32-t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uint32-t),
[int64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int64),
[uint64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uint64),
[int128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int128)

Comment: `uint32` is a valid type in C#.  `uint32_t` is not.

Comment: I can totally see that on a CV: _unit32: expert; int64: working knowledge_.

Comment: One can be an expert in the integer types of a particular language and its common implementations. So perhaps what you're looking for are `c-inttypes` (whose synonyms would include the versions with `-t`) and `c#-inttypes` (whose synonyms would include the versions without `-t`).