# Burninate [boolean]/[int]/[string]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

Nobody is an expert in any of these things, and they're far too vague to be useful. Looking at the top questions for each ([boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boolean), [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string), [int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int)) doesn't show anything where the type tags actually matter. Most are either simple questions about conversion, or questions about unrelated things where the code happens to involve one of them.

Comment: I'd agree with [boolean] and [int], but [string] could maybe be kept, since there can be encoding issues that might arise.

Comment: And what about the people who worked hard for a bronze `boolean` badge? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1956/boolean)? On a more serious note, I agree with the request.

Comment: @ChristopheD:  I'm *sure* that they're experts in the same categories that cover the use of `boolean`.

Comment: Fairly closely related to [Should we delete the \[string\] and \[array\] tags because they have no experts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255242) (possibly duplicate?)

Comment: @ChristopheD - Jonskeet got that almost exactly 2 years ago.  Amazing.

Comment: @CDspace: why not just tag it with [encoding] or [UTF-8] then?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel you are correct. I didn't think of that until later

Comment: Some time ago we had a [string-manipulation] tag, it was very useful IMO. Then it was synonymed to [string]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97715/what-happened-to-the-string-manipulation-tag (which I personally think is not that useful). Getting rid of [string] would be an amazing end to this story :D.

Comment: Motivated by quality or motivated by farming edits?

Comment: The top 2 questions I see for [boolean], are important questions which are exactly relevant to booleans: one about conversion to bool in C++ (using `!!` - specific to bool) and one about bitwise operators.

Comment: Maybe related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255684/tags-uint32-and-uint32-t-are-synonymous

Comment: what about [String] when used as a Value type vs. Reference type questions? What about the [String] class in C#? [int] - hm.. what about extension methods?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a waste of time.

There's 3700 questions tagged `boolean`; they'd all have to be fixed one at a time. The notion that `string` needs to be removed is ridiculous, so why are we saying that some data types are valuable while others are not? Makes zero sense to me.

Angels dancing on the head of a pin.

Comment: "It's a waste of time." Bot? String is fine since it isn't misused as much. But when is a question every about ints and bools (that isn't in the 10 only possible questions)?

Comment: The community seems to think that removing tags without also fixing the questions is a terrible thing, so a bot will not work.  That a tag can be abused is not sufficient reason, by itself, to declare a tag bad.

Comment: If it's abused more than used correctly, it's bad. If it's bad enough and there's enough questions, a bot would work.

Comment: Looking at the first 10 or so newest posts in the `int` tag, there are two questions that don't need the tag, but the rest do.  I've already removed the tag from the offending questions, but there's no point in removing it from questions that discuss the `int` data type prominently and specifically.

Comment: 2? Out of 15, 4 are crap, and the rest mostly aren't about `int`, but `type-conversion` or just `types` in general.

Comment: Well, I've stated my case.  I think you guys should reserve your effort for tags that are genuinely a nuisance.  Data types are a prominent feature of programming languages, so categorically stating that some data types don't deserve their own tag is specious.

Comment: I agree that such tags are useless. I would propose to make them synonym of some other tag but which? Such tag would be useless as well. Maybe data-types?

Comment: @LeosLiterak These tags don't contain enough information to know what the question is really about.  Presumably the questions already have a language tag - if not, we won't be able to tell which language tag is needed from these tags.

Comment: @Brilliand: Then add a language tag.  Most questions (that get any attention) already have one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey My point was that there's no synonym that these tags could be redirected to that would add anything to the question, or be merged in with an existing tag in most cases.

Comment: @Brilliand: That happens.

Answer (score 5):

You say that no one is an expert in strings; this reveals more about your lack of expertise than anyone else's.

There are a number of string-processing algorithms (things like Levenshtein distance or Rabin-Karp search) with applicability to almost any language, and someone absolutely can be an expert in these string-processing techniques.

It may be true that most [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) questions deal more with details of a particular string type and language-specific functions... but that doesn't mean that generic cross-language string questions can't exist.  [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) needs to stay.